# Cretaing Min and Max priority queue in C++ stl

Tags: c++, stl, priority-queue, comparator

```
priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, std::greater<int> > pq;
```

greater uses the operand >. SO it means the integer with greater value should have higher priority. But in this priority queue , the integer with smaller value is having higher priority.

```
  priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, std::less<int> > pq;
```

less  uses the operand <. SO it means the integer with lesser value should have higher priority. But in this priority queue , the integer with greater  value is having higher priority.

I am getting confused in both of them.

Comment: What are you confused about? That is the way `priority_queue` works, and you seem to have figured it out by yourself too.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue